# How to obtain the max. value of n-period for every row based on values of another columns in a dataframe?

Tags: numpy, dataframe

Let's say I have a df:

```
idx   c1   
A     1  
B     7  
C     8  
D     6  
E     5  
F     6 
G     9 
H     8 
I     0 
J    10
```

What's the fastest way to obtain the highest value for n-periods for every row based on c1, then create a new column for it? Eg. if it's 3-period, then it will be like this:

```
idx   c1   new_col
A     1     0
B     7     0
C     8     0
D     6     8      (prev. 3-period, 1,7,8, 8 is the highest)
E     5     8      (prev. 3-period, 7,8,6  8 is the highest)
F     6     8      (prev. 3-period, 8,6,5  8 is the highest)
G     9     6      (prev. 3-period, 6,5,6  6 is the highest)
H     8     9      (prev. 3-period, 5,6,9  9 is the highest)
I     0     9      (prev. 3-period, 6,9,8  9 is the highest)
J    10     9      (prev. 3-period, 9,8,0  9 is the highest)
```

My current code is now:

```
list=[]
for row in range(len(df)):
    if row < 3:
       list.append(0)
    else:
       list.append(max(c1[row-3:row]))
df['new_col'] = list
```

This method is very slow because I have many rows and this has to loop through the whole thing. Is there a faster way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just `rolling` and `shift`:

```
df['new_col'] = df['c1'].rolling(3).max().shift().fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
  idx  c1  new_col
0   A   1      0.0
1   B   7      0.0
2   C   8      0.0
3   D   6      8.0
4   E   5      8.0
5   F   6      8.0
6   G   9      6.0
7   H   8      9.0
8   I   0      9.0
9   J  10      9.0
```